# String Splitting on upper case but retain upper case substrings

Tags: python

Say I have:

```
myString = 'myPERLPythonJavaScriptJavaTextSample'
```

I would like to split this as:

```
['my', 'PERL', 'Python', 'Java', 'Script', 'Java', 'Text', 'Sample']
```

What is/are the PYTHONIC way(s) of doing this?

I should have been clearer :-(.  Here is another example of what I am after:

myString2 = ['myAbcDEFGhijklMNOP']

should return:

['my', 'Abc', 'DEF', 'Ghijkl', 'MNOP']

'...DEFGh...' becomes '....', 'DEF', 'Gh...' because 'G' is the last character of the string of upper cases 'DEFG'.  That is, we split at the penultimate upper case letter, if there are more than one successive upper case letters. This does not apply for the last substring: return 'MNOP' as is.

Comment: How are you supposed to split `PERL` from `Python`? The capitalization of `PERL` makes that nearly impossible.

Comment: Consider a list with `myPERLHTMLPython` how would you propose we know how to split this?

Comment: Please read [my answer to an other question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5020906/#9283563). This will be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to separate words with spaces then split:

```
import re 

myString = 'myPERLPythonJavaScriptJavaTextSample'
myString = re.sub(r'((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|(?<!\A)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))', r' \1', myString)
result = myString.split()
print result
```

returns: ['my', 'PERL', 'Python', 'Java', 'Script', 'Java', 'Text', 'Sample']

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments you can't get this exactly but you can come close and post-process it:

```
myString = 'myPERLPythonJavaScriptJavaTextSample'

ll = []
val = ''
for ch in myString:
    if ch.isupper():
        ll.append(val)
        val = ''
    val += ch

print ll
>> ['my', 'P', 'E', 'R', 'L', 'Python', 'Java', 'Script', 'Java', 'Text']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expressions:

```
import re
myString = 'myPERLPythonJavaScriptJavaTextSample'
regex = '([a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z][a-z]+)'
ll = filter(None, re.split(regex, myString))
print ll
```

Which returns:
['my', 'PERL', 'Python', 'Java', 'Script', 'Java', 'Text', 'Sample']

[enter link description here](https://eval.in/521248)